# OR and && combination in javascript not working as desired

Tags: javascript, html

I'm an accounts person. I have prepared some code to automate a format I need for my tax payment purpose. Everything is fine except this || and && combination. For example in the following code I have assigned some tax rates and text of "Ltd." "Limited" etc so that if (for example) the tax rate is 3% and the supplier's name contains the word "Limited" or "Ltd." etc, then the Status column of my table should show "COMPANY" else "INDIVIDUAL".

```js
function coStatus(RATE_OF_WHT, NAME) {
sString = "";
if (RATE_OF_WHT == "4" || RATE_OF_WHT == "7" || RATE_OF_WHT == "8" || RATE_OF_WHT == "14.5" || RATE_OF_WHT == "15" || RATE_OF_WHT == "2" && NAME.includes("LTD") || NAME.includes("LIMITED") || NAME.includes("Ltd") || NAME.includes("Limited")) {sString = "COMPANY"}
else if (RATE_OF_WHT == "155" || RATE_OF_WHT == "3" || RATE_OF_WHT == "6" && NAME.includes("LTD") || NAME.includes("LIMITED") || NAME.includes("Ltd") || NAME.includes("Limited")) {sString = "COMPANY"}
else {sString = "INDIVIDUAL"}
return sString;
}
```

The problem is that even if the supplier's name doesn't contain the word "Ltd." or "LIMITED" etc, it still shows the STATUS as "COMPANY" whereas ideally if the word "LIMITED" isn't there, it should just show the STATUS as "INDIVIDUAL". Hope you get my point. Need your help!

Comment: what is the intended logic? You need to give us sample values of `RATE_OF_WHT` and `NAME`, along with what you expect the function to return for the, and what it actually returns.

Comment: @RobinZigmond RATE_OF_WHT and NAME is a column of tax rates and suppliers names respectively in a table I have designed. I have already explained my condition. That if certain tax rates && (and) the Supplier's name contain the words "Limited" "Ltd." etc, the value in my STATUS column should show "COMPANY" otherwise if the supplier's name doesn't contain any of the assigned words i.e. "Ltd" or Limited" etc, value in STATUS column should be equal to "INDIVIDUAL". I hope it makes sense now!

Comment: no, not really. Your code clearly says you want the result `"COMPANY"` whenever `RATE_OF_WHT` is equal to certain "magic" values like `4` and `7`, regardless of what the `NAME` is - but your description doesn't mention this. I can't fix your code until I know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: oh, I just saw the edit - that does make it a bit clearer.It looks like you're thinking that `||` takes precedence over `&&`, when in fact it's the other way round. So you need to structure it as `if ((... || ... || ...) && (... || ...|| ...))`. (Although there are much neater and more maintainable and readable ways to write this!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the groupings in your logic expression.

In the first if statement you need to group the OR operators before and after the AND operator. Otherwise, it is evaluating every operator individually.

So simple fix. Just add a few sets of parentheses to group the operators before and after the `&&`.

```
function coStatus(RATE_OF_WHT, NAME) {
    sString = "";
    if ((RATE_OF_WHT == "4" || RATE_OF_WHT == "7" || RATE_OF_WHT == "8" || RATE_OF_WHT == "14.5" || RATE_OF_WHT == "15" || RATE_OF_WHT == "2") && (NAME.includes("LTD") || NAME.includes("LIMITED") || NAME.includes("Ltd") || NAME.includes("Limited"))) {sString = "COMPANY"}
    else if ((RATE_OF_WHT == "155" || RATE_OF_WHT == "3" || RATE_OF_WHT == "6") && (NAME.includes("LTD") || NAME.includes("LIMITED") || NAME.includes("Ltd") || NAME.includes("Limited"))) {sString = "COMPANY"}
    else {sString = "INDIVIDUAL"}
    return sString;
}
```

It is a subtle change, but note the extra parentheses in the the `if` and `else if` expressions.

Comment: Thanks! I just removed one bracket from the portion where it's been used thrice. The code is working absolutely fine now!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is lack of parentheses.

When it sees

```
a || b && c || d
```

it's interpreted as

```
a || (b && c) || d
```

not as

```
(a || b) && (c || d)
```

You need to add parentheses as follows

```
if ((RATE_OF_WHT == "4" || RATE_OF_WHT == "7" || RATE_OF_WHT == "8" || RATE_OF_WHT == "14.5" || RATE_OF_WHT == "15" || RATE_OF_WHT == "2") && (NAME.includes("LTD") || NAME.includes("LIMITED") || NAME.includes("Ltd") || NAME.includes("Limited"))) {sString = "COMPANY"}
else if ((RATE_OF_WHT == "155" || RATE_OF_WHT == "3" || RATE_OF_WHT == "6") && (NAME.includes("LTD") || NAME.includes("LIMITED") || NAME.includes("Ltd") || NAME.includes("Limited"))) {sString = "COMPANY"}
```

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. `&&` is more precedent than `||` so that expression is in fact parsed as `a || (b && c) || d`

Comment: @Rocky Sims I have tried your solution and now the whole code isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, @RobinZigmond you're right. My bad. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @TaimoorAhmed are you sure you replaced just those two lines with my version of those 2 lines? I've double checked my syntax and it still looks right. What error(s) are you seeing in the console when you try my solution?

Comment: @RockySims Thanks! you solved my problem! I just removed one bracket where it's been used thrice. Now the code is working absolutely fine!!!